# No route matches [GET] "/find_user.png"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use angularjs in my new rails application. I put my angularjs html file in `app/assets/angular/templates` and put `css` and `js` file in `app/vender`. Now when I run project, `css` and `js` file load correct, but I don't know how can I use images. I put my image besides html file, but when I run project, I get below error in chrome console:

```
ailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

`assets/angular/templates/index.html`:

```
<li class="text-center">
    <img src="find_user.png" class="user-image img-responsive"/>
</li>
```

`image path`:

`assets/angular/templates/find_user.png`

`server log`:

```
Started GET "/find_user.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-12 14:41:09 +0430

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/find_user.png")
```

I set root in `config/application.rb`, but again I get error:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app","assets","angular","templates")
```

How can I use my images in html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still do want to take images from your custom folder under assets. You use unchanged application.rb . But now you need to append "/assets/" in image src. Like

```
<li class="text-center">
   <img src="/assets/find_user.png" class="user-image img-responsive"/>
</li>
```

Because if you directly put image files in public folder it will work properly but you did not get these images in precompiled assets in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

Put image to path "public/"

You will be able to separate templates and server, but in line `img src='find_user.png'` it's looking for image on current server now

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename file to assets/angular/templates/index.html.erb and use `<%= image_tag "find_user.png" %>` .

Comment: I don't want use rails tag, because I want seprate templates and server in futures. I'm searching for a way that I use images in `.html`.